# powerbi merge rows based on the column conditions

Tags: powerbi

I have an excel with below format. 1st column is the users, 2nd column is country and 3rd is the state from where all they have worked.

[image]

I want to customize it to below format using the powerbi:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in Power Query:

```
let
  Source = Table.Group(
    MyTable, 
    {"User", "Country"}, 
    {{"States", each Text.Combine(List.Sort(List.Distinct(_[State])), ","), type text}}
  )
in
  Source
```

Or, better, with a DAX measure:

```
States = 
    CONCATENATEX ( 
        VALUES ( MyTable[State] ),
        MyTable[State],
        ",",
        MyTable[State],
        ASC
    )
```

An example output table, with `User` and `Country` fields, along with measure `[States]`:

[image]

Comment: I tried this but this just gives total. When created the measure it shows as Total- D,E,F,G,H,I .Actually I want  on user basis, country and all the states. So the states of one country should be together for a user.

Comment: You need  some evaluation context - add a table visual, with fields User, Country, and measure [States]...